# XSLT sequence of numbers to range

Tags: xslt, range, sequence

In XSLT (2.0 preferred), how to convert a sequence of numbers in an array to a range of numbers, eg. `<a>1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9</a>` to `<a>1-3, 6-7, 9</a>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `for-each-group select="$sequence" group-adjacent="xs:integer(.) - position()"`:

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of separator=", ">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., ',\s*')"
                group-adjacent="xs:integer(.) - position()">
                <xsl:sequence
                    select="
                        if (not(current-group()[2])) then
                            .
                        else
                            concat(., '-', current-group()[last()])"/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Transforms

```
<a>1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 9</a>
```

into

```
<a>1-3, 6-7, 9</a>
```

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, I am still puzzled as to how `group-adjacent="xs:integer(.) - position()"` work

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen, the items in the grouping population have the positions `1,2,3,...`, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#xsl-for-each-group saying " the expression contained in the group-by or group-adjacent attribute is evaluated with that item as the context item, with its position in population order as the context position". So when we process `1,2,3,6,7,9` the grouping keys computed in `group-adjacent="xs:integer(.) - position()"` are `1-1, 2-2,3-3,6-4,7-5,9-6` which is `0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3`.

Comment: Based on that I hope your existing understanding of `group-adjacent` suffices to see that the used `group-adjacent` expression allows us to identify the adjacent sequences/groups of items which differ exactly by an increment of `1` and can be merged into a range `current-group()[1]` || '-' || current-group()[last()]`.